# Why difftime() is returning 0 when computing the time difference between dates?

Tags: r

If I compute the time difference between two dates as below:

```
start <- "2018-03-11 02:13:18"
end <- "2018-03-11 02:18:18"
difftime(end, start, units = "mins")
```

I am getting the output as:

```
Time difference of 0 mins
```

whereas it should be 5 mins.

Comment: I do get a difference of 5 min. When is the DST switch in your time zone?

Comment: ok. I think it got fixed when I ran Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT'). Thanks.